# Automatically set value on child rows when deleting parent row?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, hierarchy

**Description**

We have a table and data below :

```
Version: PostgreSQL 9.3
Table name: tree_data (id int, code text, name text, parent_id int) 
Primary key: id 
Foreign key: parent_id (refer to id)
```

and data:

```
insert into tree_data (id, code, name, parent_id) values (1, 'aaa','aaa', null);
insert into tree_data (id, code, name, parent_id) values (2, 'bbb','bbb', 1);
insert into tree_data (id, code, name, parent_id) values (3, 'ccc','ccc', 1); 

 id | code | name | parent_id
 1    aaa    aaa      null
 2    bbb    bbb      1
 3    ccc    ccc      1
```

Here our query and result we want, it means: when deleting id = 1 (parent row), table will automatically set parent_id = null in child rows (first level) .

```
delete from tree_data where id = 1 ;
----> rows after deleting: 
 id | code | name | parent_id
 2    bbb    bbb      null
 3    ccc    ccc      null
```

**Our questions:**

Can we use postgresql constraints to do it ?  If not, how we can do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create table tree_data 
(
   id integer primary key, 
   code text, 
   name text, 
   parent_id integer,
   constraint fk_parent 
      foreign key (parent_id) 
      references tree_data(id)
      on delete set null
);
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b9a62/1

Answer (score 3):

When you create a foreign key in postgres, set `ON DELETE SET NULL`.

```
ALTER TABLE public.tree_data
ADD CONSTRAINT tree_data_id_fkey
   FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
   REFERENCES tree_data(id)
   ON DELETE SET NULL;
```